Vector passed to function as reference - double free or corrupted
Inside my program, in a class constructor, I am creating a vector of unsigned int, called "pos", which is later modified using another function, to which it is passed by reference.
FockStates(int N=0, int m=0, ParticleType type=boson)
{
    
    states.clear();
    if(m>0 && N>=m)
    {
        
        std::vector<unsigned int> pos(m,0);//vector which gets corrupted
        
        if(type==fermion)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
            {
                pos[i]=i;
            }
        }
        
        bool success=true;
        
        while(success)
        {
            
            states.push_back(PosToState(pos,N,m));
            
            success=nextState(pos,N,m,type);//removing this function yields no error
        }
        
    }//exact moment of "double free or corrupted"
}

When the construction is finished, I am getting runtime error "double free or corrupted". I know this is connected to "pos", since this happens either at the exact end if "if" where it is created, or, when I moved declaration outside of if, at the exact end of function, so probably when the vector is beeind freed (which makes sense).
I've noticed also, that the problem stops, when I remove usage of "nextState" function, which takes "pos" as a reference and modifies it.
Here is "nextState" function:
bool nextState(std::vector<unsigned int> &pos, int N=0, int m=0, ParticleType type=boson)// removing this function yields no error
{
    int i=m-1;
    pos[i]+=1;
    while(true)
    {
        std::cout<<i<<"\n";
        if(i<0)
            return false;
        if(int(pos[i])>=N+type*(i-m+1))
        {
            
            pos[i-1]+=1;
            for(int j=i;j<m;j++)
            {
                pos[j]=pos[j-1]+type;
            }
            i-=1;
        }
        else
            break;
        
    }
    return true;
}

Is it possible that program tries to "clean" vector that was passed by reference?
How do I fix that?

"Is it possible that program tries to "clean" vector that was passed by reference?" - no, unless you call the relevant method on it. Posting a [mre] will help us help you.

Most likely one of the indices to operator[] is invalid. Replace all [] with .at() and you will get nice exception to debug.

Are you sure that i or j will never be zero? Or equal to / larger than pos.size()?

And have you tried to use a debugger to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values, to see what really happens?

Ok, I can see now that indeed there is nothing wrong with "freeing space" but rather with my indexing, I can see that sometimes inside the position array there are left positions bigger than array itself, so I have to fix that.

I've noticed also, that the problem stops, when I remove usage of "nextState" function, -- This is an indication that your program exhibits undefined behavior due to memory corruption.  Removing supposedly unrelated code resulting in your program behavior to change is the tell-tale sign of UB occurring.

I can see now that indeed there is nothing wrong with "freeing space" -- You tried to overcomplicate the reasoning behind what you believed the problem was.   A std::vector or basically any C++ type has the same scoping rules in terms of local, global, static, etc. variables.  The vector is not going out of scope, there is nothing to "free up".  C++ is not a garbage-collected language, unlike C# or similar language, where variables go up into a puff-of-smoke whenever the garbage collector detects that a variable is not in use.

Yes, that's true. I am however interested why does this wrong indexing show "double free" and not "segmentation fault"

Ok, I have found an error, and it has nothing to do with "freeing space".
Indeed I was sometimes asking for negative index.
As things in array get fuller, I am moving my index backwards. I have "if" which stops everything when I reach negatives, but then I'm using index i-1. i is equal to zero, so i-1 is negative.
The solution was to move the if for negatives, and actualy search for zeros.
I am however very curious why did this error give "double free or corrupted" error instead of "segmentation fault" as I've always seen.
bool nextState(std::vector<unsigned int> &pos, int N=0, int m=0, ParticleType type=boson)// removing this function yields no error
{
    int i=m-1;
    pos.at(i)+=1;
    while(true)
    {
        std::cout<<i<<"\n";
        //if(i<0)   Old index check - doesn't detect i-1
        //  return false;
        if(int(pos.at(i))>=N+type*(i-m+1))
        {
            if(i==0) return false;//new index check, detects i-1
            pos.at(i-1)+=1;//outside of check - index i is 0, but I modify i-1, so index -1.
            for(int j=i;j<m;j++)
            {
                pos.at(j)=pos.at(j-1)+type;
            }
            i-=1;
            //return false;
        }
        else
            break;
        
    }
    return true;
}


Possibly because writing on index -1 overwrites internal bookkeeping data for heap allocation (that compiler uses to remember e.g. size of allocated memory). Say, it was supposed to read 10 for 10 integers, but you overwrote it to 20 and suddenly compiler tries to deallocate 20 integers instead of 10 when vector is destroyed.However, with Undefined Behaviour it's always a guess at what happens.

Don't expect predictable behaviour from undefined behaviour.

why did this error give "double free or corrupted" error instead of "segmentation fault" as I've always seen -- You wrote out-of-bounds.  There is no guarantee what will happen.  Your program could have "worked" with this bug occurring, and you wouldn't have had any clue it was in your program (until you change the code, compiler, compiler options, or worse, a customer who has your program experiences a crash and reports to you with an angry email).
